# IDE error: Variable undefined but defined in an if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am defining the variable `NSURL *url` in a series of else if's where there cannot be an error so it will always be defined (I can add error catching later just in case).

This is a horrible way of doing this but im fairly new to the language.

```
if (whatTime == @"1000") {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yyy/json.php?f=1&time=1000"];
    }else if(whatTime == @"1100"){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yyy/json.php?f=1"];
    }else if(whatTime == @"1100"){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yyy/json.php?f=1"];
    }
```

However the debugger is telling me url is undefined. Is there a way to get around this?

When I do (above the hell-pit of ifs) `NSURL *url;` it runs but says it is not connected to the internet.

Comment: Are you sure you are stepping over the appropriate line in the debugger before inspecting the variable?

Comment: Side note - you must replace all of the `==` operators with calls to the `isEqualToString:` method calls. Example: `if ([whatTime isEqualToString:@"1000"])`.

Comment: Side note: can this whole mess be replaced with one line: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yyy/json.php?f=1&time=", whatTime]];`?

Comment: @maddy thanks for that - I will try it. As I say I am new to obj c, coming from a c background I was unsure how concatenation works - thanks!

Comment: @JoshBoothe `NSString stringWithFormat` is essentially the same as `printf`.

Comment: I made a typo in my earlier comment: Try using: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yyy/json.php?f=1&time=%@", whatTime]];`. (I forgot the `%@` just after `time=`.

Comment: @rmaddy thats great! Could you briefly explain what the %@ is for, or does it just work like a printf?

Comment: The `%@` format specifier is for Objective-C objects. Otherwise you use the same format specifiers as printf (such as %d and %f, etc.). See the docs for `stringWithFormat:` for full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the undefined problem, you have to declare `NSUrl *url` outside the if/elses:

```
NSURL *url = nil;
if (whatTime == @"1000") {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yyy/json.php?f=1&time=1000"];
}else if(whatTime == @"1100"){
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yyy/json.php?f=1"];
}else if(whatTime == @"1100"){
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yyy/json.php?f=1"];
}
```

I think the not connected problem is not related to that code.

Comment: Make sure you initialize `url` to `nil` or add a final `else` (with no `if`).

Answer (score 1):

The local variables declared inside the `if` and `else if` clauses are only visible inside those scopes and therefore you can't use them after the last `else if`. By declaring `NSURL *url;` before the `if` it will be visible after the last `else if` since it is in the same scope.

The "not connected to the internet" error is probably not related to this code. Probably your device/simulator has no connection.